# Getting "FBSDKLog: Unsupported FBSDKGraphRequest attachment" while posting on Facebook

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api

I have been trying to post on Facebook from my application using FBSDKGraphRequest but when clicked on post button it shows me an error of "Unsupported FBSDKGraphRequest attachment".

```
if FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().hasGranted("publish_actions") {
                    let parameters = ["message": ["title": "Task: \(self.textField.text!)", "textDescription": "Task Description: \(self.textAreaDescription.text!)", "dateTime": "Time: \(self.dateTime)", "location" : "Location:\(self.placemark!.locality!) \(self.placemark!.administrativeArea!)" ] ]

                    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/feed", parameters: parameters, HTTPMethod: "POST").startWithCompletionHandler({
                        (connection, result, error) -> Void in
                        if (error != nil) {

                        } else {
                           print(result)
                    })
                }
```

Gives this type of error.

[image]

Comment: were you able to fix this? it seems the problem is when trying to set a dictionary as the value of one of the parameters. in your case "message". I have the same problem with other FB API, dont know how to fix.

Comment: Yeah i fix it by declaring a whole dictionary as value and then by passing one by one by parameter from it.